# Как работают argc и argv

Tags: c++, c

Расскажите, пожалуйста, о принципе работы аргументов `argc` и `argv` в *C/C++*.

Comment: Ответ на этот вопрос есть в любом учебнике по C. Зачем об этом тут спрашивать?

Comment: А вот как можно реализировать функцию, которая принимает неограниченное количество аргументов: [stdargs.h](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdarg/va_start/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Первая типа `int` хранит количество передаваемых параметров, один из параметров - это обязательно имя программы (абсолютный путь), далее уже могут быть ваши параметры, если это ваша программа.

`argv` - это обычно массив `char`, но сейчас уже `_TCHAR`, причем указателей, но `_TCHAR` обычно в *IDE* стоит как `char`, там уже имена переданных параметров, один - это программа, а остальные - это уже их порядок.

Пример:

```
hello.exe -param1 -param2

argc = 3    
argv[0] = hello.exe
argv[1] = -param1
argv[2] = -param2
```

Вот я только с путем подзабыл. Если что, книга есть *"Пахомов Visual C\C++ 2010"*, я там такое вычитывал.

Comment: Указатель разыменовывать не надо было.

Comment: _TCHAR - доморщенный тип, в стандарте такого нету.

Comment: Это знаем, про _TCHAR, но я указал про иде, а язык и иде в сегодняшнем мире это разные вещи все же. Каждый лепит, как хочет, а стандарт скорее не для кодера, а для разработчика компилятора.

Comment: "`argv` - это обычно массив `char`" Ым... Во все века и времена `argv` был массивом *указателей*.

Answer (score 8):

- `argv` - это массив указателей на нуль-терминированные строки, содержащие *параметры командной строки*, с которыми вызывалась ваша программа.
- Если `argc` больше нуля, то `argv[0]` содержит указатель на имя вашей программы. В каком виде это имя представлено - зависит от реализации. Если имя программы не предоставляется, `argv[0]` будет указывать на пустую строку (т.е. не может быть нулевым указателем).
- Если `argc` больше единицы, то элементы `argv[1]`...`argv[argc - 1]` содержат указатели на *параметры командной строки*.
- Размер этого массива - `argc + 1` (а не `argc`, как часто ошибочно полагают). При этом гарантируется, что `argv[argc]` содержит нулевой указатель. Таким образом для того, чтобы найти конец массива `argv`, вы можете как пользоваться значением `argc`, так и просто просматривать массив `argv` до встречи с первым нулевым указателем.
- В языке С разрешается модифицировать как элементы массива `argv`, так и сами строки, указуемые элементами массива `argv` (разумеется, в пределах исходной длины строки). В языке С++ такого разрешения явным образом не дается.

Comment: Помимо чистой теории из С стандарта, стоит упомянуть как на практике с этими параметрами можно работать, к примеру, argv это просто массив С строк, который вы можете передать в `execv()` на Unix при создании нового процесса и [`argv[0]` для своих нужд можно задать](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/403887/23044) или чтобы и на Windows можно было произвольные Unicode аргументы принимать, то переносимый код должен аналог `boost::nowide::args(argc, argv)` вызвать (который `GetCommandLineW()`, `CommandLineToArgvW()` вызывает, чтобы восстановить аргументы на Винде)...

Comment: ... Или (чтобы ответить "как работают") пример [как в памяти аргументы могут располагаться](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23599762/4279)

Comment: @jfs: Это уже вопрос к автору вопроса: без уточнений - это вопрос о работе с параметрами на *принимающей* стороне. Никакой разницы между "теорией из стандарта" и "практикой" в данном случае нет. Никакой другой "практики" тут нет и быть не может. Ссылка, которую вы привели, посвящена совсем другой теме: передаче *environment* через расширенные параметры `main` в POSIX. При чем здесь это - не ясно. К тому же рассказы о том, как могут располагаться такие аргументы в памяти - это примерно то же самое, что и рассказы о том, какие числа может генерировать `rand()`.

Comment: Попробуйте передать консольному приложению через argv имя файла с Unicode символами, которые в текущей code page не представимы на Windows, и мы посмотрим, есть ли разница между теорией и практикой. Вопрос явный не что стандарт разрешает, а "как работают". Считать что мира вне стандарта не существует и отождествлять его с rand() это убого: все абстракции ущербны (all abstractions leak), поэтому видеть не только саму абстракцию, но также как она реализована (хотя бы один этаж вниз) или хотя бы как практические проблемы обойти является  полезным. И смотрите внимательней, в коде argv присутствует

Answer (score 3):

- `argc - 1` равно количеству аргументов, переданных программе в командной строке.
- `argv[1]` ... `argv[argc - 1]` - сами аргументы.
- `argv[0]` - имя программы, как ввели его в командной строке.

Answer (score 0):

#### ссылка на материал

на "*[https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/01/c-argc-argv/*"](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/01/c-argc-argv/*%22) есть статья с примерами на эту тему(сайт основан "*Ramesh Natarajan*" и только на английском языке).

##### например:

```c
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
```

тут, как сказано было выше, определяются 2 переменные для работы с аргументами командной строки.

- *int argc* - количество общих аргументов командной строки, переданных исполняемому файлу при выполнении.
- *char** *argv* - указатели на заголовок стека, где и хранится адрес нашей переменной или список переменных переданных как аргументы.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* число или argc */
    printf("arguments value:%d\n", argc); 

    /* имя проги или argv[0] */
    printf("arg_name:%s\n", argv[0]); 

    /* уже понял ;) */
    printf("expression: 'Hoy, i'm %s a programmer!'\n", argv[1]);
}
```

```sh
$ ./main Temmy
    arguments value: 1
    arg_name: Temmy
    expression: Hoy, i'm Temmy a programmer!
$
```

весь код доступен на его сайте(и там куда больше чем здесь).

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)