# Для чего в main (int argc, char *argv[])

Tags: c++

Недавно начал изучать C++ и не понимаю зачем принимать 2 аргумента? Один — целое число, а второй — массив, ещё и память выделяется как-то странно без `new`. Откуда приходят эти аргументы и зачем их используют?

Comment: К уже данным ответам могу только посоветовать для более глубокого понимания почитать `man 3 exec` и маны из `SEE ALSO` в нем.

Возможно, кроме них представляют  интерес `man system` и `man popen`.

--

Кстати, в общем случае в main передается не 2, а 3 аргумента (3-ий массив адресов переменных окружения (environment), завершающийся нулем. Он аналогичен второму, в котором передаются адреса аргументов  командной строки)

    int main (int ac, char **av, char **env);

Comment: далеко не факт, что у человека линукс. да и третий параметр - это компиляторозависимое, хотя многие поддерживают это. В принципе, никто ведь не мешал разработчикам сделать что то вида

    int main(std::vector<std::string> argv) {
      return 0;
    }

Но что то не спешат.

Comment: @KoVadim, не знаю, какие компиляторы как, а g++ в винде замечательно все это поддерживает:

    c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ g++ 3args.cpp 
    c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ ./a a1 a2
    arg
    av[0]: c:\Users\avp\src\cc\hashcode\a.exe
    av[1]: a1
    av[2]: a2
    env
    env[0]: ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
    env[1]: APPDATA=C:\Users\avp\AppData\Roaming
    ....
    env[53]: windows_tracing_flags=3
    env[54]: windows_tracing_logfile=C:\BVTBin\Tests\installpackage\csilogfile.log
    c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ 

--

Да и  `execl("a.exe", "xaxa", 0);` тоже работает.

Comment: да уж, @KoVadim с линуксом явно погорячился ))

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/6866/312941

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Это параметры командной строки, которые могут быть переданы Вашему приложению. Первый аргумент передается по той причине, что встроенные массивы в С/С++ не хранят размер и передача размера - один из способов об этом узнать (можно к примеру договориться, что последний элемент будет нулевым, но это накладывает определенные ограничения).

> память выделяется как-то странно без new

память выделяется в другом месте, а в функцию приходит только указатель. Как именно она там выделяется - в данный момент Вас тревожить не должно. Главное помнить правило - "кто память выделяет, тот обычно ее и удаляет". В данном случае компилятор вставит весь необходимый код, который выделит память и освободит. Хотя там ещё и система немного может выделить.

Как же приходят аргументы?

К примеру, Вы можете запустить программу так

```
myprog param1 param2 param3
```

в этом случае `argc` будет иметь значение 4. argv[1] будет равно param1. argv[3] будет равно param3. Возникает вопрос, а что в нулевом элементе? а там имя программы в том виде, в котором его предоставляет операционная система. То есть, там может быть как myprog, так и имя с полным путем.

Дополнительный материал:

- [Аргументы функции main(): argv и argc](http://lord-n.narod.ru/download/books/walla/programming/Spr_po_C/06/0604.htm)
- [Параметры функции main (argc, argv)](http://cppstudio.com/uchebniki/yazyk-programmirovaniya-s/parametry-funkcii-main-argc-argv/)

**upd:**
для любителей стандарта - читать пункт 3.6.1. Там в частности сказано, что официально есть два варианта - `int main()` и `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` (хотя последний можно записать как `int main(int argc, char **argv)` - суть не меняется). Все остальное - на усмотрение компиляторов.

Comment: Добавлю, что в `posix ОС` в конечном счете запуск программы (замена исполняемого кода и данных текущего процесса) производится вызовом

    int execve(const char *filename, char *const argv[], char *const envp[]);

Причем, за содержимое `argv[0]` "отвечает" программист!!! (а не система).


Следует добавить, что независимо от формы `main()` среда (третий параметр `execve()`) в `posix` всегда доступна через

    extern char **environ;

Безусловно, винда - не `posix`, но в gcc/g++ семейство `exec()` и `environ`  реализованы.

Интересно, в других виндовых C/C++ компиляторах это так?

Answer (score 5):

При запуске программы можно указать доп. аргументы в командной строке.

Первый параметр, `argc` (argument count) указывает на количество этих аргументов, а второй параметр, `argv` (argument values) содержит значения этих аргументов переданные при запуске.

Answer (score 4):

Это аргументы командной строки. argc — количество, argv — сам массив аргументов. Можете их вывести на экран и посмотреть, что получится. Нулевым всегда идет название программы, потом — что угодно.

Используется, к примеру, так: Вы пишете что-то для работы с файлами. При запуске программы вы естественно просите пользователя указать путь к файлу, с которым надо работать. Но ведь гораздо удобнее запускать программу из терминала с уже указанным параметром: `Admin:~ prog ~/Documents/file1.txt` — в этом случае терминал сам может дописать название файла или еще чего удобного сделать. А в винде можно еще файл на программу перетаскивать (вот тут я не помню точно, как название файла передается).

Опять-таки это только пример — ограничивает вас только ваше воображение.

UPD: пока писал уже ответили))

Comment: Обратите внимание, что нулевой аргумент (так же, как и остальные) контролируется вызывающей стороной, и его значение не гарантировано.

Comment: Это верно, только в gcc/g++ MinGW (винда) есть интересный ньюанс. Вот в таком коде

      char * const argv[] = {0};
      execve(av[0], argv, environ);

система(?) все-таки формирует argv[] из 2-х элементов, в argv[0] заносит имя файла с расширением.

А вот в Linux все честно - argv[0] == 0.