# вызов имён файлов в командной строке C++

Tags: c++, матрицы

Здравствуйте. Начинаю программировать в C++, у меня есть программа, которая считывает матрицы с txt файла.

```
#include <fstream>   
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUSSIAN");

//Создаем файловый поток и связываем его с файлом
ifstream in("C:\\Users\\1\\Desktop\\matriza.txt");

if (in.is_open())
{



        //Если открытие файла прошло успешно

        //Вначале посчитаем сколько чисел в файле
        int count = 0;// число чисел в файле
        int temp;//Временная переменная

        while (!in.eof())// пробегаем пока не встретим конец файла eof
        {
            in >> temp;//в пустоту считываем из файла числа
            count++;// увеличиваем счетчик числа чисел
        }

        //Число чисел посчитано, теперь нам нужно понять сколько
        //чисел в одной строке
        //Для этого посчитаем число пробелов до знака перевода на новую строку 

        //Вначале переведем каретку в потоке в начало файла
        in.seekg(0, ios::beg);
        in.clear();

        //Число пробелов в первой строчке вначале равно 0

        int count_space = 0;
        char symbol;
        while (!in.eof())//на всякий случай цикл ограничиваем концом файла
        {
            //теперь нам нужно считывать не числа, а посимвольно считывать данные
            in.get(symbol);//считали текущий символ
            if (symbol == ' ') count_space++;//Если это пробел, то число пробелов увеличиваем
            if (symbol == '\n') break;//Если дошли до конца строки, то выходим из цикла

        }
        cout << count_space;

        //Опять переходим в поток в начало файла
        in.seekg(0, ios::beg);
        in.clear();

        //Теперь мы знаем сколько чисел в файле и сколько пробелов в первой строке.
        //Теперь можем считать матрицу.


        int n = count / (count_space + 1);//число строк
        int m = count_space + 1;//число столбцов на единицу больше числа пробелов






        double **x;

        x = new double*[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) x[i] = new double[m];

        //Считаем матрицу из файла

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                in >> x[i][j];



    //Выведем матрицу
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                cout << x[i][j] << "\t";
            cout << "\n";

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) delete[] x[i];
        delete[] x;

        in.close();//под конец закроем файла
    }


else
{
    //Если открытие файла прошло не успешно
    cout << "Файл не найден.";
}

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Задача заключается в следующем: считать две матрицы с двух текстовых файлов, перемножить их и результат вывести в третий файл. Также рассмотреть все исключения. Как перемножаются матрицы в C++-с этим я разобрался.  Но мне нужно, чтоб имена трех файлов задавались как аргументы командной строки. Считать с файлов нужно две матрицы, причем не используя дублирования вышеприведенного кода. Как мне избежать дублирования кода, если мне нужно считать две матрицы и как организовать, чтоб имена трех файлов были аргументами командной строки? Спасибо!

Comment: Вы уверены, что ваш код работает?

Comment: Да, работает. Запускал.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

> Как мне избежать дублирования кода, если мне нужно считать две матрицы

```
static double **get_matrix_from_file( const char *filename )
{
    /* 
     * возвращает NULL (nullptr) в случае ошибки, 
     * иначе - содданную матрицу
     */
}
```

> как организовать, чтоб имена трех файлов были аргументами командной строки?

```
int main( int argv, char **argv )
```

[Подробней - здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/227712/).

Comment: Раз уж мы пишем на C++, а не на C, то скорее `static Matrix* Matrix::init_from_file(const char* filename) { /* выбрасывает исключение в случае ошибки */ }`

Answer (score 1):

Для начала для удобства определим структуру:

```
struct Matrix{
  double** matr;
  int x;
  int y;
};
```

Далее код считывания матрицы вынесем в отдельную функцию, которая принимает имя файла и возвращает матрицу:

```
  Matrix read_matrix(char* filename){

  ifstream in(filename);

    if (in.is_open())
    {

        int count = 0;
        int temp;
        while (!in.eof())
        {
        in >> temp;
        count++;
        }

        /*Тут нужно было поменять две команды местами, сначала очищаем
        флаги потока, а потом переводим каретку на начало, а не наобороты*/
        in.clear();
        in.seekg(0, ios::beg);

        int count_space = 0;
        char symbol;
        while (!in.eof())
        {

        in.get(symbol);//считали текущий символ
        if (symbol == ' ') count_space++;
        if (symbol == '\n') break;

        }
        cout << count_space;

        in.seekg(0, ios::beg);
        in.clear();

        int n = count / (count_space + 1);
        int m = count_space + 1;

        double **x;

        x = new double*[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) x[i] = new double[m];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            in >> x[i][j];

        in.close();
        return (Matrix){x, n, m};
    }
    else
    {
    cout << "Файл не найден.";
    return (Matrix){0,0,0};
    }
}
```

И далее просто работаем с этой функцией, считывая аргументы программы стандартным способом, например так:

```
int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUSSIAN");

    if(argc < 4) exit(0);

    Matrix m[3];
    for(int i(1); i < 4; ++i){
      m[i-1] = read_matrix(argv[i]);
      show_matrix(m[i-1]);
    }

    for(int j(0); j < 3; ++j){
      for (int i = 0; i < m[j].x; i++) delete[] m[j].matr[i];
            delete[] m[j].matr;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за алгоритм! Но хотел бы уточнить пару моментов: в строках   return (Matrix){0, 0, 0}; и return (Matrix){x, n, m}; подчеркивается красным фигурная скобка и пишет "требуется выражение"..? И блоке, где считываются аргументы- show_matrix не определен. Где он определяется?

Comment: Show_matrix нужно написать самому, а почему оно подчеркивает красным и что-то пишет: наверное иде такая, эта конструкция анонимной структуры была еще в си, но ее можно заменить на Matrix m = {nullptr, 0,0}

Comment: Ещё тогда вопрос: как мне грамотно записать условие: если количество столбцов (n) первой матрицы  равно количеству строк (m) второй матрицы-производить умножение. Иначе-ошибка. ?

Comment: В обыкновенном условии if

Comment: Это понятно. Как мне обратиться к переменным: количеству столбцов первой матрицы и количеству строк второй матрицы? Как мне эти значения вызвать?

Comment: например, у нас матрица `Matrix m`, тогда `m.x` и `m.y` чтою получить их значения