# Отличие программы в книге

Tags: c, компиляция

Начал изучать язык С.Хочу узнать почему в книге "Язык программирования С" Кернигана и Ритчи программа выглядит вот так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* печать таблицы температур по Фаренгейту
и Цельсию для fahr = 0, 20, ..., 300 */
main()
{
    int fahr, celsius;
    int lower, upper, step;
    lower = 0; /* нижняя граница таблицы температур */
    upper = 300; /* верхняя граница */
    step = 20; /* шаг */
    fahr = lower;
    while (fahr <= upper) 
    {
        celsius = 5 * (fahr-32) / 9;
        printf ("%d\t%d\n", fahr, celsius);
        fahr = fahr + step;
    }
}
```

В функции `main()` нет никаких аргументов. При компиляции вылезает ошибка. Но когда с помощью SumlimeText3 я писал эту программу, то он предложил сделать так `int main(int argc, char const *argv[])`

Почему так происходит? Почему в книге не верная программа?

P. S.
Если что я компилирую с помощью gcc компилятора в Ubuntu 16.04.2

Comment: Вы не используете никаких переменных окружения, поэтому это не так уж и важно, что у Вас нет ```argc``` и ```argv```. Укажите, какая ошибка появляется при компиляции.

Comment: Может у Вас появляется не ошибка, а предупреждение (*warning*)?

Comment: https://github.com/anotherlin/tcpl (Читайте README там)

Comment: Вы что то выдумываете. Ошибка при компиляции тут, конечно, должна вылезать, но отнюдь не из-за того, что у функции `main()` нет никаких аргументов. С аргументами у вас как раз все в порядке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте сравним функции:

1. `main()`
2. `int main(int argc, char const *argv[])`

*Первое отличие* - не указан тип функции (`int`). В этом не ошибки, если Вы не укажете тип, то компилятор сам подставит `int`.

*Второе* - не аргументов `int argc, char const *argv[]`. Это аргументы командной строки, их нужно писать только, если Вы собираетесь их использовать. (*здесь подробный ответ что это и зачем -* [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/227712/%D0%94%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2-main-int-argc-char-argv)).

Так что программа верна, хотя и не совсем привычна.

**P.S.**

Лично у меня программа компилируется, но выдает одно предупреждение (о чем и было написано выше):

```
warning: return type defaults to 'int'
 main()
 ^
```

Как было указано ниже в комментарии *0andriy*, можно избавиться от этого предупреждения, если при компиляции указать флаг `std=c89`.

Comment: Второе  — лишнее. Используйте указания компилятору, что исходник ANSI C.

Answer (score 3):

Даже второе (последнее на текущий момент) издание книги "Язык программирования С" Кернигана и Ритчи было написано и издано до того, как язык С был впервые стандартизован. После выхода первого стандарта языка текст книги был подправлен "задним числом", но большинства примеров кода, использованных в книге, эти правки не коснулись. С тех пор стандарт языка менялся, но книга, понятное дело, в соответствие с новыми стандартами С не приводилась. По этой причине данная книга сегодня представляет лишь в основном историческую/развлекательную ценность. А примеры кода в ней и ранее были низкокачественными/устаревшими.

Что касается приведенного вами примера, то если закрыть глаза на многочисленные стилистические недостатки, очевидно ошибочным в нем является только объявление функции `main`. Оно опирается на два [взаимосвязанных] свойства *достандартного* языка С: правило "неявного int" и правило "пустой decl-specifier-seq". А именно, в достандартном С разрешались объявления вида

```
a = 42; /* Пустая decl-specifier-seq */
foo();  /* Пустая decl-specifier-seq */
main(); /* Пустая decl-specifier-seq */
```

Они, однако, запрещены в стандартном языке С, начиная с самого первого его стандарта. Первый стандарт языка С, принятый в 1989 году (т.наз С89/90, он же - "ANSI C") сохранил правило "неявного int", но отменил возможность использования "пустого decl-specifier-seq", что сделало нелегальным вышепроцитированные объявления. В С89/90 можно объявить, например,

```
const a = 42;  /* Непустая decl-specifier-seq, но подразумевается неявный `int` */
static foo();  /* Непустая decl-specifier-seq, но подразумевается неявный `int` */
extern main(); /* Непустая decl-specifier-seq, но подразумевается неявный `int` */
```

но ни в коем случае не просто `foo()`, `main()` или `a`. Современный же язык С (начиная с С99) больше не поддерживает и правило "неявного int", т.е. в современном С тип в объявлении всегда необходимо указывать явно

```
const int a = 42;
static int foo();
int main();
```

Также можно заметить, что в языке С не рекомендуется использовать объявления функций с пустыми скобками `()`. Такие объявления являются устаревшими (obsolescent) с самого первого стандарта языка, хотя окончательно запретить их никто до сих пор не осмелился. Функции без параметров в языке С должны объявляться как `(void)`, а не как `()`.

И еще  можно заметить, что отсутствие явного `return` в функции `main` в С89/90 приводит к тому, что возвращаемое функцией `main` значение не определено. Только начиная с С99 завершение `main` по последней закрывающей скобке подразумевает неявный `return 0;`.

Comment: Замечальный ответ. Плюсую. :)