# параметры функции main argc argv

Tags: c++

Для написания каких программ может понадобится параметры функции main argc argv ?

Comment: Примеры сложных программ с использованием argc argv? Да простейший пример - компилятор GCC. Принимает 100500 параметров через командную строку. :-)

Comment: Практически любое консольное приложение. Да ,конечно, можно в них обойтись без этих параметров, а написать запрос данных у пользователя. Но это будет, мягко говоря, неудобно для пользователя

Answer (score 2):

Для программ, куда вы будете передавать данные в программу из вне.

`argc` - показывает сколько "объектов" мы передаем программе на входе (читай - при запуске)
`argv[]` - сами объекты

То есть вы можете передавать объекты сразу в программу и уже работать с ними на лету.

[Тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/227712/%D0%94%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2-main-int-argc-char-argv) это подробно описано.

Comment: Хочется увидеть примеры сложных программ с использованием этих параметров.

Comment: @Razor0109 хотеть не вредно, но на вопрос дан ответ.