# Как реализовать разбор опций командной строки в Linux?

Tags: c, командная-строка

Никак не могу разобраться как передать два параметра (нужно задать значение матрицы через командную строку). В итоге передается только один, а второй игнорируется.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int N = 0, M = 0, i = 0, j = 0;
    int opt;
    char op;
    char* opts = "a:o";

    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, opts)) != -1) {
        switch (opt) {
            case 'a': {
                N = atoi(argv[optind - 1]);
                M = atoi(argv[optind]);

                i = N, j = M;

                break;

                case 'o': {
                    op = optarg[0];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вы  хотя бы напишите  примеры, что хотите передавать в командной строке.

Comment: Необходимо передать размерность матрицы. К примеру, я передавала 2 и 3, но моя программа считывала только 3, создавая одномерный массив, равный 3.

Comment: @Lessi, у вас очень странно вложены `case`-ы `switch`.

Comment: Вопрос лучше переименовать, в Передача и разбор аргументов приложения. А то в голове картинка ключи для /bin/sh  с Вашей формулировкой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если необходимо просто передать размерность матрицы, то к чему вам вообще лишние сложности с `getopt`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc >= 3) {
        const long width = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
        const long height = strtol(argv[2], NULL, 10);

        printf("%ldx%ld\n", width, height);
    }
}
```

*Про аргументы командной строки (а также `argc` и `argv`) смотрите в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/227713/185348) ответе. Про `strtol` можно почитать [здесь](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol).*

Comment: Далее планируется работа с матрицей (на самом деле с несколькими). Чтение из фала, запись в файл, действия с матрицами. Я в программировании новичок, с остальным разобралась, а задать размерность матрицы через командную строку не знала как правильно, потому искала способ как реализовать и наткнулась на способ с getopt несколько раз.

Answer (score 2):

Предлженный eanmos вариант имеет тот недостаток, что если Вы перепутали местами параметры, то программа этого не обнаружит. Ещё хуже, если вы просто забыли задать один или даже оба параметра. Программа упадёт..

Более приемлемый вариат - просто немного подправить ваше решение:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int N = 0, M = 0;
    int opt;
    char op;
    char* opts = "a:o:";

    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, opts)) != -1) {
        switch (opt) {
            case 'a':
                N = atoi(optarg);
                break;

           case 'o': 
                M = atoi(optarg);
                break;

           default:
                printf("Ошибочная опция!\n");
        }
    }

    printf("Введены значения N = %d, M = %d\n", N, M);
    return 0;
```

Тогда при вводе параметров в командной строке получим:

```
$ ./a.out -o7 -a5
Введены значения N = 5, M = 7
```

Это - то, что вы хотели?

Comment: +1. Хотя программа, конечно, не упадет, если проверять `argc` :)