# Запустить программу с измененным именем процесса

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Как запустить программу с измененным именем процесса?

Comment: Вас интересует как сменить имя  в выводе команды ps?

Насколько я понимаю, это содержимое  файла /proc/PID/comm и самому записывать туда что-либо нельзя.

Можно попробовать сделать линк с другим именем на свой argv[0] и выполнить exec с этим файлом, перезапустив себя в том же процессе, но под новым именем (оно появится в /proc/PID/comm, содержимое /proc/PID/cmdline тоже поменяется в соответствии с аргументами exec).

Comment: связанный вопрос: [How to change argv0 in bash so command shows up with different name in ps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3251550/how-to-change-argv0-in-bash-so-command-shows-up-with-different-name-in-ps)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3251550/how-to-change-argv0-in-bash-so-command-shows-up-with-different-name-in-ps

Answer (score 4):

Существует два независимых "имени процесса": одно происходит от имени самого исполняемого файла `path`, другое определяется `argv[0]` из командной строки.

Оба параметра передаются [`exec*()` функции, которая используется для запуска исполняемых файлов на POSIX (путём замены текущего процесса, чаще всего после форка)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html):

```
execvp(path, argv);
```

`exec -a` команда в баше, упомянутая @WiT, изменяет `argv[0]` при вызове `execv*()` функции. В `zsh` можно определить `ARGV0` с тем же эффектом:

```
$ ARGV0=new-name your-command arg1 arg2
```

Чтобы изменить `path` для нового процесса, можно создать линк, как @avp предложил:

```
$ ln -s $(command -v your-command) new_name
```

Изнутри уже запущенного процесса, можно вызвать [`prctl()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/prctl.2.html), чтобы изменить "настоящее" (основанное на `path` имя процесса):

```
prctl(PR_SET_NAME, title, 0, 0, 0); /* title is upto 16 chars */
```

`argv[0]` так же можно поменять изнутри процесса. Изменение `argv[0]` не гарантировано что будет работать -- [PostgreSQL предоставляет переносимую реализацию, в которой можно посмотреть все явные ужасающие детали этой процедуры](http://doxygen.postgresql.org/ps__status_8c_source.html).

Посмотреть на имена можно с помощью `ps` команды:

```
$ ps axk comm o comm,args
```

Эта команда показывает оба типа имени.

Answer (score 1):

В Bash это делается так: **exec -a ИмяКотороеХотим ИсполняемыйФайл Аргументы**

Answer (score 0):

```
$ perl -e "\$0='VErrrry Cewl NaMe';while(<STDIN>){}"
```

И:

```
$ ps fax | grep Cewl
28193 pts/9    S+     0:00          |       |   |       \_ VErrrry Cewl NaMe
```