# Почему argv[0] выдаёт полный путь к скрипту? (Python)

Tags: python, argv

Выполняю упражнения из LearnPythonTheHardWay. Везде, где используется argv, у автора первый аргумент содержит имя файла скрипта (например, "ex14.py"), у меня же выдаётся полный путь к этому файлу - "D:_MyCode\Python\LPTHW\ex14.py" (запускаю из cmd). От чего это зависит? Что и где нужно изменить, чтобы argv[0] содержала просто имя скрипта?

Comment: Теоретически, ЕМНИП, `argv[0]` может содержать вообще что угодно, а имя скрипта там оказывается просто при «обычном» способе запуска

Comment: @andreymal для винды argv[0] заполняется вызывающим процессом и там действительно можно написать что угодно. Или ничего.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> От чего это зависит?

[Документация для `python <script>` формы запуска](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html) говорит, что`argv[0]` содержит то, что задано в командной строке:

> If this option is given, the first element of `sys.argv` will be the
>   script name as given on the command line.

Если вы видите полный путь, значит используемый вами способ запуска скрипта передаёт полный путь  `python` команде (например, когда  `.py` файловое расширение ассоциировано c `python.exe` на Windows).

То есть, если вы руками запустите `python ваш-скрипт.py` в командной строке (из директории, содержащей `ваш-скрипт.py` файл), то `sys.argv[0]` будет просто `'ваш-скрипт.py'`.

> Что и где нужно изменить, чтобы `argv[0]` содержала просто имя скрипта?

Не смотря на то, что это технически возможно, переопределить как скрипт вызывается, например, создать bat-файл, который `cd` в [директорию со скриптом перед его запуском (что может изменить его текущую рабочую директорию)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/535318/23044), этого не следует делать, потому что получить требуемую строку можно в самом скрипте, не рискуя сломать запуск других питон-программ на системе.

Если хочется получить имя именно из `argv[0]`:

```
import os
import sys

progname = os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])
```

В общем случае, `argv[0]` не обязано указывать на скрипт на диске, см. [Запустить программу с измененным именем процесса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/385246/23044).

Модуль может иметь `__file__` атрибут, из которого можно также изъять имя файла. Он не всегда определён, например, когда модуль запущен, используя `execfile()` встроенную функцию. Связанный вопрос: [How to properly determine current script directory in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3718657/4279).

Также, имя модуля не обязано быть связано с именем файла—модуль не обязан вообще в каком-либо файле находится. Если модуль исполняется как скрипт, то `__name__ == '__main__'`.

В тему используемой командной строки и её связи с argv списком: [Full command line as it was typed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/667540/4279).

Answer (score 3):

```
C:\Users\XXX>type t.py

    import sys
    print sys.argv[0]
    print __file__
    import os
    print os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])
```

Вывод:

```
C:\Users\XXX>python ./t.py
./t.py
./t.py
t.py
```

Answer (score 2):

Зависит от того, как вы запускаете скрипт.

```
path_to_python\python.exe script.py
```

или

```
script.py
```

если в системные пути добавлена папка питона и файлы с расширением *.py ассоциированы с питоном

Comment: Я прописал в PATH путь к питону и к папке со скриптами, так что скрипты я запускаю просто как "script.py" отовсюду, без указания полного пути.

Comment: запускайте свой скрипт как `python.exe script.py`

Comment: Так вообще не работает - "No such file or directory"

Comment: Пропишите путь  к питону в **переменные среды** в *path*. В консоли зайдите в каталог со скриптом (`cd c:\path_to_script`). Выполните `python.exe script.py`

Comment: Да, работает только если вызывать, находясь в каталоге со скриптом. Спасибо! Есть ли способ получать только имя скрипта, если вызывать его из другого места? (возможно, где-то что-то подкрутить в каких-то настройках?)

Comment: Однако, почему, находясь в папке со скриптом, вызовы "script.py" и "python script.py" дают разный результат?

Answer (score 0):

Получить имя файла на диске(Независимо от места запуска):

```
import os
print(__file__) # полный путь к файлу
print(os.path.basename(__file__)) # только имя файла
```

Comment: `__file__` довольно часто не указывает полный путь к файлу. Вы бы хотя бы ответы других читали сначала.