# Как получить имя запущенного процесса?

Tags: python, python-2.x

Как получить имя запущенного процесса(самого приложения python)?Т.е был у нас foo.py мы его запустили и он должен определить как себя зовут.

Comment: В *nix есть два имени процесса: из пути исполняемого файла и из argv[0]. См. [Запустить программу с измененным именем процесса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/385246/23044)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import sys

script_name = sys.argv[0]
```

Comment: Хм.. Работает. https://ideone.com/dvIEhY. А я ожидал там сам питон увидеть :)

Comment: @Qwertiy если бы запускалось через интерпретатор, то был бы питон :)

Comment: Т. е. его запускают просто как файл? Я на винде к такому не привык)))