# Как реализовать копирование аргумента в буфер Windows (Visual studio)

Tags: windows, visual-studio, cmd

Всем привет, недавно начал вспоминать VS, и появилась идея сделать микроприложение с маленьким функционалом.Суть в том что при нажатии ссылки `"testprog:testarg01001011abc"` открывается моё приложение которое я задал по умолчанию.По идее это тоже самое что я запущу `testP.exe` с аргументом `testprog:testarg01001011abc`.Возник вопрос, а могу ли я скопировать в буфер обмена каким-либо образом этот аргумент при запуске приложения? т.е. при нажатии на ссылку `"testprog:testarg01001011abc"` открывается моё приложение и копируется в буфер обмена строка `"testprog:testarg01001011abc"` и при вставке в текстовом редакторе и т.д. будет `"testprog:testarg01001011abc"`

Comment: ЯП не указан... https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/6866/Как-работают-argc-и-argv

Comment: извиняюсь, забыл упомянуть что ЯП C#